# Google cloud build trigger static site: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ascii, gzip, gsutil, static-site

My building process for the static site is as follows:

1. I create the `public` folder
2. I copy the `public` folder and rename to `gzipped`.
3. On the `gzipped` folder I run following code: `find . -type f -exec gzip "{}" \; -exec mv "{}.gz" "{}" \;`
4. Then I push my repo and the build is automatically triggered.

When I include a € character in my `.md` file like following, then I get below error. Apparently it does not like special characters written like so `- €1000` in my `.md` file (I guess the dash `-` is the culprit):

```
tags:
- tag1
- €1000
- tag2
- tag3
```

Here the error:
`Step #4: Caught non-retryable exception while listing file://./gzipped: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-12: ordinal not in range(128)
Step #4: CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync`.

How to fix my `tags listing` with an € in front of a dash?

Comment: did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "push to my repo", I assume you're using the `gsutil rsync` command, mostly due to the error message you're getting, which comes from this line of code:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/65d6a3e30e2ad51279841a8b58008a5396568ddd/gslib/commands/rsync.py#L645

Glancing at the code there, I'm not sure why gsutil would be trying to use the ASCII codec. My two best guesses are:

- Maybe you're running an old version of gsutil that has some encoding bugs? You can run `gsutil version` to check.
- Maybe you're running this in a terminal/environment that uses ASCII (or something that doesn't support unicode characters) as its default encoding? I'm assuming from the `find` command that you're running on a Linux or macOS system -- if so, from your shell, you can check what Python thinks the default encoding is with:

```
$ python -c "import locale; print(locale.getdefaultlocale())"
```

This is emitted in my terminal, which uses UTF-8 as the default encoding:

```
('en_US', 'UTF-8')
```

Finally, if that isn't helpful, you'll probably want to get a bit more info than just the summary text shown in your error message - you could try adding in some extra `print` statements near the line I linked above, in your local gsutil installation (in the `<path-to-gsutil>/gslib/commands/rsync.py` file). Ideally, you'd want to view the whole stack trace to see where the error came from, so adding something like `print(traceback.format_exc())` in the body of that `except:` block would be useful.

Comment: thanks to your help, i was able to pinpoint the problem, please see my edit in original post.